# Retrieving users by their age efficiently

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a PostgreSQL database of users and their birthdays and want to get all users in a specific age range:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE age(birthday) >= 21 AND age(birthday) <= 30;
```

How can I achieve that this query stays efficient, even when there are millions of users in the database?
Of course there are more filters, I just don't want to calculate the age for every row.

I do not want to use a materialized view.

Comment: Were you intending to refer to the actual built-in 'age' function, which returns an INTERVAL type and cannot be directory compared to an integer?  Or was that just a notation for something you want us to fill in for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the computation from the column, to the other side of the inequality operators where you have literals rather than a column:

```
WHERE birthday >= current_date - interval '30 years' AND birthday <= current_date - interval '21 years';
```

Then a simple index on "birthday" will make it efficient.  It might need some fiddling depending on what datatype "birthday" is.  I tested it as a `timestamp without time zone`.

Answer (score -1):

I can think in several ways:

Create an index on birthday field

```
CREATE INDEX users_birthday_idx ON users(birthday);
```

Then i would change the query a little

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE birthday >= (now() - interval '21 years') AND birthday <= (now() - interval '30 years');
```

Another approach is indexing age function output, this works but in previous experiences query optimizer did not work as well as is an index of table data.

```
CREATE INDEX users_age_idx ON users(age(birthday));
```

And if you are repeating query values a lot you can also think in a partial index on fixed ranges

If this is not enough maybe you need to create table partitions.

Comment: You can't create an index on `age(birthday)` because the function isn't stable

Comment: Its mandatory to use inmutable functions @a_horse_with_no_name?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the value stored in the index would not match the value which is compared later

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT * FROM users WHERE age(birthday) >= 21 AND age(birthday) <= 30;

You might consider rewriting this so that it only performs the *calculation* once. 
(PostgreSQL *probably* does this for you, but might be worth checking).

```
SELECT ... 
FROM users 
WHERE age(birthday) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 ;
```

(Don't use "select *" in Production code - discussed many times before).

An index on birthday *might* help.

```
CREATE INDEX table1_birthday ON table1 ( birthday );
```

While PostgreSQL *does* support [Function-based indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-expressional.html), I don't think they'll help here, because the calculation is *non-deterministic* - the result potentially changes every time you run it so, sadly, you *can't* do this:

```
CREATE INDEX table1_age ON table1 ( age( birthday ) );
```

Comment: The index on `birthday` won't help for `age(birthday) BETWEEN ...` and the index using `age( birthday)` can't be created because `age()` is not a stable function